# Is it correct to use the superlative word "best" as a verb according to prescriptive grammar?

Tags: grammar, verbs, superlative-degree

I've often stumbled across phrases like these (perhaps not the last one) and felt that they sounded a bit awkward:

> Nothing can best the sheer capacity of […]
>
> X would best Y any day.
>
> I best you.

I'm a layman in terms of grammar. At first, I just wanted to see if this is correct by any standard (which it appears to be). Then I came across the fact that there seems to be two factions (in lack of better a word) comprised by people specializing in [descriptive](http://grammar.about.com/od/d/g/descrgramterm.htm) and [prescriptive](http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/prescgramterm.htm) grammar, of which I may lean more towards the latter. So, in conclusion, I seek to know if the above examples are *unequivocally* correct according to **prescriptive** grammar.

Comment: Funny just how many things people write off to "the Internet today". The verb *best* predates the noun *Internet* by a hundred years.

Comment: This isn't a question of grammar but of semantics (and possibly morphology).

Comment: Kudos for the sheer temerity of asking for a _prescriptive_ answer on what _does_ indeed boil down to semantics. I wonder how many people go around with outdated dictionaries shouting that the word _mouse_ can **not** be used for an electronic device because their dictionary says it's an animal.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I may as well be wrong, but I think it's fairly accurate to believe the verbing of e.g. "best" to be an increasing trend 'lately' – copywriters might be an informed group of people to comment on that – but regardless of which, the question isn't focused on language history.

Comment: @oerkelens I could do with this comment over on the 'What “Extravagant culture” could be used as an antonym to “Spartan”?' thread.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Well, I intended this to be a question of prescriptive grammar and I was looking for an answer that informs me on the grammatical correctness in the examples that I referenced. It seems odd to me that grammar, by itself, can't rule whether my examples are correct or not.

Comment: I think the purpose of this site is in describing English language and usage accurately, not prescribing it. Descriptions of prominent or widespread prescriptions would be on topic, but I think our own prescriptions would not be.

Comment: @Henrik But "Can you explain, with an argument based on virtually **any** sort of grammar, why the sentence 'Colorless green ideas sleep furiously' is largely considered unacceptable?" famously has the answer 'No'. It's perfectly grammatical. // 'Best', like many words, displays intercategorial polysemy: it can acceptably be used as noun, adjective, adverb or verb, as [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Best) tells us. 'Round' is even more versatile, having an incarnation as a preposition also. And 'just' exists as parts of speech you almost certainly don't believe in.

Comment: Certainly "best" has been commonly used as a verb by sporting event reporters since I was a child, and I definitely predate the Internet.

Comment: Should be clarified or closed as unclear: no question has been posed. Is the question whether those two examples are "valid"? Or is it about the origin of *best* as a verb? Or is it something else?

Comment: @anyone Question amended to avoid confusion. It's beyond the scope of the question whether the verbing of superlatives predates the advent of Internet. I just wanted to know if, according to present-day grammar, a phrase like "You best me" is unequivocally correct. Which, I gather, it is.

Comment: *Prescriptive* according to who, sorry, whom? There is no governing board of English. And dictionaries are meant to be descriptive.

Comment: CarSmack and @Drew I certainly acknowledge the existence and raison d'etre of different perspectives on grammar use. While being opposites of one another, I think it's sound to say that prescription and description can inform each other. As the examples posed in my question would be open for both descriptive and prescriptive answers, I chose to focus on the latter; my question merely tries to evaluate the validity of using superlatives such as "best" as verbs (e.g. "I best you"), according to those who adhere to linguistic purism and prescription. Whom those people are, exactly, I don't know.

Comment: @bdsl This appears to me as if this site, by itself, *prescribes* a focus on descriptive language questions and answers. :)

Comment: Yes. The site prescribes how to use the site. I don't think it should generally prescribe how to use English.

Comment: I think the idea that there are two sorts of grammar - prescriptive and descriptive, and you can choose which to study - is misleading. There is grammar, and there are two activities you can get involved in - describing it and prescribing it.

Comment: Seems like there is correct (descriptive) and incorrect (prescriptive) involvement in English on this site. I apologize for not knowing that.

Answer (score 5):

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=best&searchmode=none) tells us:

> best (v.) Look up best at Dictionary.com
>   "to get the better of," 1863, from best (adj.). Related: Bested; besting.

I'm afraid the authors of etymonline are describing the usage they find, and (luckily!!!) not trying to establish *how* people should use words, so I cannot (and out of principle, *will* not) appeal to your hunger for a prescriptive answer.

But as it seems, *best* has been used as a verb since 1863, which means it predates, as RegDwight mentioned, the internet by a hundred years. It may well be that *you* have only come into contact with the verb due to the internet, but I doubt the internet itself contributed to the popularity of the verb.

As to the grammatical validity, notwithstanding your love for prescriptive grammar, *it does not hold water*. You can find a thousand grammarians saying that verbing an adjective is wrong, they *will* be bested by a population that *uses* the language and tells them where they can put their "rules". Generations have been taught that "I am good" is not grammatical and others that the verb *have* is always followed by *got*. Again others have been told not to use the passive voice, by someone who didn't even understand what the passive voice was. A lot of wasted effort, but if you like that stuff, I'm afraid you may not find as many supporters here as you may have wished.

Comment: Very well said.

Comment: OED's earliest citation for *best* as a verb is 1839. That may well have been added within the last fortnight.

Comment: @Andrew, I don't think I've ever seen someone use the word *fortnight* in earnest before. I love EL&U.

Comment: @DanBron 'fortnight' is very common in the UK.

Comment: @oerkelens Thanks for a well put explanation. I've narrowed my question and removed the reference to Internet (which kind of led the question the wrong way). I'm inclined to accept this answer, but wonder if you're saying that this would not be valid in terms of prescriptive grammar? (I understand if you don't want to answer that.) All in all, many great Christmas Holiday wishes from a curious Swede.

Comment: @Henrik: You asked for a _prescriptive grammar_ source, and I only used a _descriptive semantic_ source. If you find the answer useful, it's up to you to accept it or not, but my answer does not comply with the rules that you have set in your question (admittedly, I had no intention to comply ;) ). Best wishes to you as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Further to oerlekens and the OED saying that "best" has been used as a verb since 1863, I found it as a verb in Shakespeare's *[Henry VI Part 2 (act 2, scene 3)](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=qSQ4AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA164&dq=%22i%20never%20saw%20a%20fellow%20worse%20bested%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=IuCSVOrnCo3vOZLbgcgD&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22i%20never%20saw%20a%20fellow%20worse%20bested%22&f=false)*. This was probably written in 1591.

```
I never saw a fellow worse bested,
Or more afraid to fight, than is the appellant,
The servant of this armourer, my lords.
```

Admittedly, the meaning given in the footnote ("*i.e. worse conditioned*") is not the meaning I would attribute to "to best", but there it is.